# Elementary proof that $2x^2+xy+3y^2$ represents infinitely many primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms

We did in class $x^2+y^2$, which was easy, and we had for homework $2x^2+2xy+3y^2$, which I did (its values (if not square) must be divisible by form primes, or of the form $x^2+5y^2$, and clearly they can't all be the latter!).

Just to test my method I took the middle coefficient down by one - and ran into trouble...

Comment: Perhaps you ran into unexpected trouble because you picked a form of discriminant -23, which is the first time the class number is 3, so you'll need to juggle values of three quadratic forms.

Comment: Also, whereas in the other cases you looked at the primes that are represented by the given form are determined by a congruence condition modulo the discriminant (e.g. $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ in the case of $x^2 + y^2$, and conditions mod $20$ for the form $2 x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2$) there is no such congruence condition for determining the prime represented by your form of discriminant $23$.

Comment: +1 for trying to generalize an assignment-shows thinking about the issues.

Comment: Dear Simplequestions, Do the comments by me and KCd mean anything to you?  If so, great!  If not, is there some point you would like to have elaborated?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments! Hopefully next semester I will learn a non-elementary proof :) (Hilbert Class Fields and L-Series - sounds like an interesting course)

Comment: You might find this book interesting: http://books.google.com/books?id=pSMlAQAAIAAJ

Comment: I'm missing something. Aren't there an infinite number of primes for y=1, ie "2*x^2*x+3". If you mod "2*x^2+2*x+3" by any prime p, there are at most two values of x (per p) that mod to 0. Can you build a proof from that?

Comment: @barrycarter: no. Actually a result of this form is not known for _any_ polynomial of degree greater than $1$.

Answer (score 14):

This example morally comes from class field theory. It is just easy enough that I can do it using elementary algebraic number theory but not class field theory.

Write $\theta = (1+\sqrt{-23})/2$; it obeys $\theta^2-\theta+6=0$. Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$. This is the ring of integers in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$. It turns out that the class group of $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}/3$, representatives for the three ideal classes are:
$$I_0:= \langle 1 \rangle,\ I_1:=\langle 2, \theta -1 \rangle,\ I_2:=\langle 2, \theta \rangle.$$
I leave this for you to check from the standard Minkowski bounds. Note that $I_1 I_2 = \langle 4, 2(\theta-1), 2 \theta, 6 \rangle = \langle 2 \rangle$, so $I_1^{-1} = (1/2) I_2$ and vice versa. Note for future use that we are giving a $\mathbb{Z}$ basis for the latter two ideals, and that $\langle 1, \theta \rangle$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $I_0$.

An arbitrary ideal equivalent to $I_0$ is of the form $\langle x+y\theta \rangle$, and we have $N(\langle x+y\theta \rangle) = x^2 - xy + 6 y^2$. An arbitrary ideal equivalent to $I_0$ is of the form $\langle x+y\theta \rangle$ in precisely two ways, because the unit group of $R$ is $\pm 1$. So
$$\# \{ I \subseteq R : \ I \sim I_0 \ \mbox{and} \ N(I) = n \} = \frac{1}{2} \# \{(x,y) : x^2 - xy + 6y^2 =n \}. \quad (1)$$

Similarly, an ideal equivalent to $I_1$ is of the form $\alpha I_1$, for $\alpha \in I_1^{-1} = (1/2) I_2$. This $\alpha$ looks like $(1/2) (2 x + y(\theta -1))$ for some integers $x$ and $y$ and we have $N(\alpha I_1) = N(\alpha) N(I_1) = (x^2 - xy +3 y^2/2) \cdot 2 = 2x^2 - 2xy + 3 y^2$ (exercise!). Running through the same argument as before:
$$\# \{ I \subseteq R : \ I \sim I_1 \ \mbox{and} \ N(I) = n \} = \frac{1}{2} \# \{(x,y) : 2 x^2 - xy + 3y^2 =n \}. \quad (2)$$
Similarly, 
$$\# \{ I \subseteq R : \ I \sim I_2 \ \mbox{and} \ N(I) = n \} = \frac{1}{2} \# \{(x,y) : 2 x^2 + xy + 3y^2 =n \}. \quad (3)$$

Call these numbers $a_0(n)$, $a_1(n)$ and $a_2(n)$. We want to know that $a_2(p)$ is positive for infinitely many primes.

We have unique factorization into ideals in the ring $R$. So we have the analog of the Euler product
$$\sum_n \frac{a_0(n) + a_1(n) + a_2(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{(1- p^{-s})^{a_0(p)+a_1(p)+a_2(p)}}.$$

Let $\omega$ be a primitive cube root of unity. Since the class group is $\mathbb{Z}/3$, with $[I_1]^2=[I_2]$ and $[I_1]^3=[I_0]$, we also have the identities:
$$\sum_n \frac{a_0(n) + \omega a_1(n) + \omega^2 a_2(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})^{a_0(p)}} \frac{1}{(1-\omega p^{-s})^{a_1(p)}} \frac{1}{(1-\omega^2 p^{-s})^{a_2(p)}}.$$
$$\sum_n \frac{a_0(n) + \omega^2 a_1(n) + \omega a_2(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})^{a_0(p)}} \frac{1}{(1-\omega^2 p^{-s})^{ a_1(p)}} \frac{1}{(1-\omega p^{-s})^{ a_2(p)}}.$$

Define these three sums to be $L_0(s)$, $L_1(s)$ and $L_2(s)$. Using equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$, and approximating sums by integrals, we see that $L_0(s)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$ while $L_1(s)$ and $L_2(s)$ are bounded as $s \to 1$. Using explicit numerical computation, one can check that $L_1(s)$ and $L_2(s)$ do not vanish at $s=1$.

Now the end game is exactly like the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions: take logs of the above equations to deduce that
$$\log \left( \frac{1}{s-1} \right) + O(1) = \sum \frac{a_0(p)+a_1(p)+a_2(p)}{p^s} + O(1)$$
$$O(1) = \sum \frac{a_0(p)+\omega a_1(p)+ \omega^2 a_2(p)}{p^s} + O(1)$$
$$O(1) = \sum \frac{a_0(p)+\omega^2 a_1(p)+ \omega a_2(p)}{p^s} + O(1)$$

We thus have
$$\sum \frac{a_2(p)}{p^s} = (1/3)\log \left( \frac{1}{s-1} \right) + O(1) \ \mbox{as}\ s \to 1^{+}$$
and, in particular, $a_2(p)$ is nonzero infinitely often.

---

So, where is the class field theory?  For $R$ the ring of integers of a number field, $H$ the class group of $R$, and $\chi: H \to \mathbb{C}^*$ a nontrivial character, define $L(\chi, s) = \sum_{I \subseteq R} \chi([I]) N(I)^{-s}$. If you wanted to generalize this proof to an arbitrary quadratic number field, you would want to know that $L(\chi, s) \neq 0$. For any particular $R$ and $\chi$, you can prove this by hand. In Dirichlet's theorem, the analogous result [can be proved](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25794/shortest-most-elegant-proof-for-l1-chi-neq-0/25805#25805) by looking at the zeta function of the cyclotomic field. In the general case, it can be proved by looking at the $\zeta$ function of the class field -- but only once you know this exists!

Comment: David, in your equations (1), (2), and (3), you forgot to include "= n" on the right side each time.

Comment: Also, you wrote a primitive cube root of unity as $\chi$ and then at the end of the answer you use $\chi$ for a character (more standard notation).  Why not use a more standard notation for the cube root of unity, say $\omega$?

Comment: Thanks, those are good suggestions.

Answer (score -3):

If you are willing to accept Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression, then you can assume there are infinitely many primes of the form 4n + 3. Your form generates such numbers when y=1 and x is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Yes, but you are not guaranteed to get infinitely many such primes this way. As I mentioned in the comments, a result of this kind is not known for _any_ polynomial in one variable of degree greater than $1$.

Comment: @Qiaochu: My bad. Yes there will be an infinite number of numbers congruent to 3 mod 4, but I have no way of knowing infinitely many of them are indeed prime. Once again, I have proved the old adage "Haste makes waste."