# How to find prime elements

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, computational-algebra, function-fields

Let $K$ be an arbitrary number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers.

I have seen many **concrete examples** about finding prime elements. For example I calculated the prime elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, or $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

But how does this works in general? Exist an algorithm, which finds (some of) the prime elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$?
Moreover does every ring of integers of a number field contains at least one prime element?

Additionally what happens if I consider function fields instead of number fields?

Comment: You should clarify if you really want prime elements, prime ideals or irreducible elements. This three sets are the same for the examples you wrote, since they are PID.

Comment: I really want prime elements.

Comment: With a properly defined norm function in a UFD, if $N(n)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $n$ is prime. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ you see that $N(2 + i) = 5$, which is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, while $N(5) = 25$.

Comment: Yes, but this only works for a UFD, because in this case prime elements and irreducible elements are the same. In the general case I only get that if $N(n)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $n$ is irreducible. [And of course only if the field of integers looks like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$]

Answer (score 0):

Hint concerning the "Moreover"-question: Try to use Euclid's argument to show for (some) $K$, that $\mathcal{O}_K$ has infinitely many prime elements. For quadratic number fields see

[Infinitely many primes in the ring of integers for any quadratic field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35883/infinitely-many-primes-in-the-ring-of-integers-for-any-quadratic-field)

Comment: What do you mean by the Euclid's argument? Does it work for non euclidean domains?

Comment: I assume he means the proof that infinit many prime numbers exist. This is also called [Euclid's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem).